# tkn - could not find the requested resource

Tags: tekton

Running [these](https://tekton.dev/docs/getting-started/pipelines/) examples, when getting to:

```
tkn pipelinerun logs hello-goodbye-run -f -n default
```

I get this error:

```
Error: the server could not find the requested resource (get pipelineruns.tekton.dev hello-goodbye-run)
```

The pipeline is there:

```
kubectl get pipelinerun -A
NAMESPACE   NAME                SUCCEEDED   REASON      STARTTIME   COMPLETIONTIME
default     hello-goodbye-run   True        Succeeded   9h  


kubectl api-resources | grep pipelineruns
pipelineruns                       pr,prs                                 tekton.dev/v1beta1                     true         PipelineRun

tkn version
Client version: 2020-04-01T10:57:38Z
Pipeline version: unknown
```

Info: I am running on Apple arm64, if that could be an issue. I don't think as all pods are running.

Comment: That doc doesn't mention creating that pipelinerun in the default namespace. Can you share a `kubectl get pipelinerun -A`?

Comment: Thanks, it was just for trying to help tkn I added the namespace :-) I updated  the question.

Comment: Well. that does not make any sense. At least, with kubectl, it looks correct. Could it be some issue with api versions, maybe? `kubectl api-resources | grep pipelineruns` should show supported apiversions for that object. Also check `tkn version`: which version are you using. Any chance tkn client would be too old for your operator, or vice versa?

Comment: Good suggestions - thanks, I have updated questions with you commands.

Comment: sounds like a very old client. Mine just says `Client version: 0.5.0` ... and it's a shame: late 2020. Let's both upgrade: https://github.com/tektoncd/cli/releases. And let us know if that helped

Comment: I installed it using: https://tekton.dev/docs/cli/

Comment: Linux Debian: sudo apt update;sudo apt install -y gnupg etc.

Comment: ... and? Could you upgrade? Did it help?